# How to dynamically setup DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, cloud-hosting, chef

I trying to setup as part of a study a PaaS (Platform as a service) for Ruby on Rails applications. I have already played with Amazon EC2 and Chef creating EC2 instances based on Chef's recipes and roles.

Now I need to be able to give every "customer" account or every app a unique subdomain like app1.mydomain.com, app2.mydomain.com, etc. which points to my customer's app on an EC2 instance. I then need to allow the customer to point their domain to their customized subdomain (app1.mydomain.com, app2.mydomain.com).

Can someone explain to me how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

It's a Simple Matter Of Programming.  You should have something that maps customers to instances, like a database (assuming you're not going to run everything through a single frontend proxy) and then a script or whatever to generate the DNS zone from that data.

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a [cookbook](http://ckbk.it/dynect) for dynamically setting DNS entries in DynDNS Inc's Dynect API.

You could also use one of our published cookbooks for [djbdns](http://ckbk.it/djbdns), [powerdns](http://ckbk.it/pdns) or [unbound](http://ckbk.it/unbound).